# Manual post-build action missing in jenkins 2.0

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-2

[This option](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin#DeliveryPipelinePlugin-ManualTriggers) was available when I was on jenkins 1.65. Today I moved to jenkins 2.0 with a fresh install on a new machine. I don't see this option.

This option is necessary for our delivery pipeline view. So pipeline has 2 steps:

1. When a new commit is made in github, a suit of tests run.
2. If above passes, then manual deployment step will have a play button. Else not.

We were able to achive this in earlier version of jenkins but not in 2.0.

Please guide what could be missing or suggest any other viable alternative.

[image: Post-build Actions]

Answer (score 11):

Solved. It has got nothing to do with Jenkins version.

We need to have [Build Pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) installed as well. This plugin adds manual step support. And then [Delivery pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin) shows *Trigger manual build* (▶) for the manual steps.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[Updated answer for those looking at this after 2018]

The Post-Build Actions button only show up on "Freestyle" jobs.  However, it is not recommended to use the Post-Build Actions (or the old "Build Pipeline" and "Delivery Pipeline" plugins) for a build or delivery pipeline.  Rather, it is [now recommended](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/top-10-best-practices-jenkins-pipeline-plugin) to use the "[Pipeline Plugin](https://jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/)" and the "Pipeline" job type.

With this method, the hook for triggering the next job in the pipeline is defined in the Pipeline Script.  Below is an example using the "Declarative Pipeline" syntax ([preferred](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#compare)).

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Invoking some other Jenkins job') {
            steps {
                echo "Building my-other-job-name"
                build job: 'my-other-job-name', parameters: [string(name: 'OTHER_JOB_PARAM_KEY', value: "OTHER_JOB_PARAM_VALUE")]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can daisy-chain your jobs in this manner, or have a single pipeline job that chains a bunch of build/deploy jobs together.

Answer (score 1):

To create the pipeline syntax for posting to Slack channel, simply fill in your details as shown by picture below.

[image]

Find this settings in the Pipline Syntax.

[image]